# Is the client/server using TCPIP valid in the Windows environment also?

Tags: windows, sockets, tcp

In Linux environment we use the following functions

- socket()
- bind()
- listen()
- accept()
- send()/recv()

Do these system calls work in Windows environment too? If not, what are the calls available in windows to implement a client using socket programming with TCPIP?

Comment: Take a look here - http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#windows

Comment: Natively the Winsock API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740632(v=vs.85).aspx